# How to find the missing records in Track Table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 Tables like below

```
workitem

workId WorkName Status
1      xyz      16
2      abc      16
3      mnc      16

WorkItemTrack
TrackID  workId   Status
1        1        3
2        1        5
3        1        9
4        2        5
5        2        9
6        3        3 
7        3        9
```

For each "workId" in the WorkItemTrack table the staus should set to 3,5 & 9. in the above case for the workId 2 & 3 the "status" 3 & 5 are missing respectively.

In the above WorkItemTrack Table for the "workId" 2 & 3 the Status 3 & 5 are missing respectively. How to find these 2 records in the above case

Comment: You are going to need to explain that a little more thoroughly. I can't follow what you are asking. For example, define "Missing" 3 & 5 appear to be in that table from what I'm looking at.

Comment: Answer forthcoming, but you might want to re-think that structure if it requires keeping the content of two tables synchronized like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do it.

```
Select * FROM WorkItem 
WHERE WorkID Not in 
(
  SELECT Distinct WIT.WorkID 
  FROM WorkItemTrack WIT
       JOIN WorkItemTrack WIT1 ON (WIT.WorkID = WIT1.WorkID) AND (WIT1.Status=5)
       JOIN WorkItemTrack WIT2 ON (WIT.WorkID = WIT2.WorkID) AND (WIT1.Status=9)
  WHERE WIT.Status=3
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Working with small changes

Comment: What changes did you need so I can update the answer for others?